# Language Scheme: find the sum of proper divisors

Tags: scheme, racket

I am wondering how to write a function calculating the sum of proper divisors of a integer greater than 1.

```
(define (sum-of-proper-divisors n)
          (cond
           [(= n 1) 1]
           [(= 0 (remainder n (sub1 n)))
            (+ (remainder n (sub1 n)) (sum-of-proper-divisors (sub1 (sub1 n))))]
           [else (sum-of-proper-divisors (sub1 n))]))
```

This is the code that I wrote, however, it does not work. It will never stop evaluating because it will always do n-1. And I don't know how to fix this. Also, there might be other problems. How to put the restriction that makes the function stop evaluating when the divisor becomes 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the number `n` whose divisors you want to find, with said divisors. Notice that `n` never changes, what must be modified at each step is the current integer being tested (a possible divisor). For that you'll need to pass around *two* parameters:

```
(define (sum-of-proper-divisors n i)
  (cond
    [(= i 1) 1]
    [(= (remainder n i) 0)
     (+ i (sum-of-proper-divisors n (sub1 i)))]
    [else (sum-of-proper-divisors n (sub1 i))]))
```

Call it like this, at the beginning `i` must be one unit less than `n`:

```
(sum-of-proper-divisors 10 9)
=> 8
```

If having two parameters bothers you there are several ways to pass a single parameter, for instance using a named `let`:

```
(define (sum-of-proper-divisors n)
  (let loop ((i (sub1 n)))
    (cond
      [(= i 1) 1]
      [(= (remainder n i) 0)
       (+ i (loop (sub1 i)))]
      [else (loop (sub1 i))])))
```

Comment: But I am trying to find the sum of proper divisors, your code seems to calculate the sum of all divisors. I think i must be equal to n-1 at the beginning. Am I right?

Comment: @Cylia yep, that's right. I had missed the fact that they were _proper_ divisors. I updated my answer with the correction

Comment: One more question, if I want to use this function as a helper for another function with only one parameter n, would this function still work? I am wondering it is not gonna work as I have two parameters in this function.

Comment: @Cylia just use this function as a helper, called from the one-parameter function. Or use a [named `let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#(part._.Named_let)) to internally define the two-parameter function, while leaving the outer function with one-parameter. Anyway, there's no way to avoid creating another function, you _need_ two parameters, otherwise it won't work (as you observed, in your code)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use "named let". In the main function, will it work if I call (sum-of-proper-divisors n (sub1 n))?

Comment: @Cylia just use an external a helper function, or define an inner function with the helper. This is very very easy to do, there are many  ways to write the solution, having a different number of parameters is the simplest of problems, don't get confused with this.

Comment: @Cylia always my pleasure! :)