# How to count the amount of proper divisors between a number and a list of numbers?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

```
(define (proper-divisor? n m)
  (eq? (modulo n m) 0))

(define (1..10)
  list (iota 10 1))

(define (amount-of-proper-divisors n numbers)
  (length (filter (lambda (x) proper-divisor? n x) numbers)))
```

how to filter out non-proper divisors?
tried:

```
(filter (lambda (x) proper-divisor? n x) numbers))
```

ps.1: found a similar question: [Language Scheme: find the sum of proper divisors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760269/language-scheme-find-the-sum-of-proper-divisors)
which version is better? putting together a filter with a predicate and list generator or the solution in the linked question?

Comment: Use `=` to compare two numbers (not `eq?` which works for fixnums only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are missing a set of parens:

```
(filter (lambda (x) (proper-divisor? n x)) numbers)
                    ^                   ^
                    here            and here
```

The expression without the parens:

```
(lambda (x) proper-divisor? n x)
```

is the same as:

```
(lambda (x) x)
```

Comment: is there any tool that would show this type of errors? is this a static semantic error type?